# How to disable a List of buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a number of buttons on a Windows Form. I only want to disable a number of them.

I have created a list of buttons and added the buttons that i want to disable. When i run the code the buttons are still enabled.

Below is what i have tried.

```
private List<Button> buttonsToDisable = new List<Button>();
 buttonsToDisable.Add(btn1);
 buttonsToDisable.Add(btn2);
 buttonsToDisable.Add(btn3);

foreach (var control in this.Controls)
            {
                if (control is Button)
                {
                    Button currentButton = (Button)control;

                    if (buttonsToDisable.Contains(currentButton))
                    {
                        currentButton.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can anyone see why this wont disable the button for me.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: where are the buttons? are they direct child of the Form ?

Comment: In your example, change 'foreach (var control in this.Controls)' to 'foreach (var control in buttonsToDisable)'

Comment: The Controls collection only contains the direct children of a control or Form. So any buttons that sit on a panel or tab etc will not be in it. You could write a recursive funtion or simply use the list you already have, which is much more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply?:

```
foreach(Button btn in buttonsToDisable)
{
    btn.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I was over thinking this completely Thanks this works

Answer (score 0):

If is directly added to the form, then u just foreach Controls collection and disable buttons.

```
     Button btn1 = new Button();
     this.Controls.Add(btn1);

     Button btn2 = new Button();
     this.Controls.Add(btn1);

     Button btn3 = new Button();
     this.Controls.Add(btn1);

     buttonsToDisable.Add(btn1);
     buttonsToDisable.Add(btn2);
     buttonsToDisable.Add(btn3);

     foreach (var control in this.Controls)
     {
        ((Button)control).Enabled = false;
     }
```

or

```
foreach (var button in buttonsToDisable)
         {
            button.Enabled = false;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
currentButton.Enabled = false;
this.Controls.Add(currentButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

answering your question - your code would work if the buttons were direct descendants of the form - i.e. they were placed straight onto it.
If however you placed them in another container (e.g. a groupbox), then your code would need to change to something like:

```
 foreach (var control in groupBox1.Controls)
```

If you have multiple levels of complexity, then you'd be looking at a recursive function to get to the buttons within their parents, and their parents, etc.

As others have pointed out, you could always just iterate over buttonsToDisable.